# How to make a string 1st letter caps, 2nd letter noncaps, 3rd letter caps, 4th letter noncaps...?

Tags: ruby, string

I want to change:

```
word = "Stackoverflow is awesome!"
```

into:

```
"StAcKoVeRfLoW Is aWeSoMe!"
```

I did:

```
result = ""
a = word.length
odd = (1..a).select(&:odd?)
even = (1..a).select(&:even?)
odd.each {|i| even.each {|b| result += word[b].to_s}}
result # => "akvrlwi wsm!akvrlwi wsm!akvrlwi wsm!akvrlwi wsm!akvrlwi wsm!akvrlwi wsm!akvrlwi wsm!akvrlwi wsm!akvrlwi wsm!akvrlwi wsm!akvrlwi wsm!akvrlwi wsm!akvrlwi wsm!"
```

Comment: I see some mistakes in your code:

 1. You want to turn some characters of your `word` string into upcase characters, but you never call the method `String#upcase` in your script.
 2. You are only adding to the `result` variable the characters you want to modify, but you forgot to add those that need no modification.
 3. In line `odd.each {|i| even.each {|b| result += word[b].to_s}}` you are performing `odd * even` iterations. Keep in mind that the `word`variable is of length `odd + even`. Hope this helps you find your solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"Stackoverflow is awesome!"
.gsub(/(.)(.)?/){$1.upcase + $2.to_s.downcase}
# => "StAcKoVeRfLoW Is aWeSoMe!"

"Stackoverflow is awesome!"
.gsub(/./).with_index{|s, i| i.even? ? s.upcase : s.downcase}
# => "StAcKoVeRfLoW Is aWeSoMe!"

"Stackoverflow is awesome!"
.gsub(/..?/, &:capitalize)
# => "StAcKoVeRfLoW Is aWeSoMe!"
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! @sawa

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple more methods that have not been mentioned.

```
text = "Stackoverflow is awesome!"

text.downcase.dup.tap { |t| (0...t.size).step(2) { |i| t[i] = t[i].upcase } }
  #=> "StAcKoVeRfLoW Is aWeSoMe!"

e = [:upcase, :downcase].cycle
"Stackoverflow is awesome!".gsub(/./) { |c| c.send e.next }
  #=> "StAcKoVeRfLoW Is aWeSoMe!"
```

Both of these work if `text` contains a mix of upper- and lower-case letters.

Comment: I knew you were going to use cycle.

Comment: @sawa, I knew you knew that and would say so, and suspect that you knew that I knew that you knew. When it comes to enumerators I have no self-control.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably more clever ways to do this, but I think this is one of the clearest:

```
text = "Stackoverflow is awesome!"

for i in 0...text.length do
  if i.even?
    text[i] = text[i].upcase
  else
    text[i] = text[i].downcase
  end
end

puts text

# Output:
# StAcKoVeRfLoW Is aWeSoMe!
```

Answer (score 1):

```
word = "Stackoverflow is awesome!"
word.scan(/(.)(.)/).inject('') {|s,(x,y)| s << x.upcase << y.downcase}
# => "StAcKoVeRfLoW Is aWeSoMe"
```

- http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-scan
- http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject

---

**Update**

Removed dependency on second regex match, like in Sawa's answer.

```
word = "Stackoverflow is awesome!"
word.scan(/(.)(.)?/).inject('') {|s,(x,y)| s << x.upcase << y.to_s.downcase}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? "Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved."

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
word.downcase.chars.map.with_index { |c,i| i%2==0 ? c.upcase : c }.join
#=> "StAcKoVeRfLoW Is aWeSoMe!"
```

Comment: Why do you do `downcase` to the whole string?

Comment: @sawa I did this so the default setting is lowercase meaning I do not have to deal with it in the ternary operator. For example currently my code works for `word = "STACKOVEFLOW IS awesome!"` because of the `downcase` method.

Comment: Why is doing it as a default better than doing it in the ternary? I fail to see the intent of your example in the comment.

Comment: @sawa It's not a better way only that it seemed like the natural way for me to approach the problem. Removing `downcase` from my answer would still work for the OP's `word` but would fail for my example in the comment above, it just served as a demo.

Comment: Why would it fail? Isn't this what is expected? `"STACKOVEFLOW IS awesome!".chars.map.with_index { |c,i| i%2==0 ? c.upcase : c.downcase }.join # => "StAcKoVeFlOw iS AwEsOmE!"` Or, are you claiming that applying `downcase` once is better than calling it (possibly) multiple times?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I feel I misunderstood your first comment, ignore my example in the comments. As for why I `downcase` the whole string, it's as I said above- I have no reason as such. But your last theory is interesting.

Comment: Agreed. Interesting point: _"applying `downcase` once is better than calling it (possibly) multiple times?"_ `String#downcase` directly vs on char within `Enumerable &block`, when each char already requires iteration (or not)—one of those benchmarks you save for rainy days.

Comment: It's a rainy day, so I ran the benchmark. I'm not saying it's better, however applying `downcase` once is faster: https://gist.github.com/awesome/6a2693f7dc7f917944ea1b08697149f2